# Accepting drops of volumes on Dock icon

Tags: cocoa, macos, drag-and-drop, dock

I'm writing a Cocoa application that needs to accept drops of mounted volumes on its Dock icon. It is not document-based; I intend to dispatch each volume to the appropriate handler in `application:openFiles`.

I have gotten the Dock to light up my application's tile for the drag, but upon dropping, my application shows an alert: “The document [volume name] could not be opened. [My application] cannot open files of this type.” My `application:openFiles:` method never runs, even though the delegate is hooked up and is sent other delegate messages.

So, what's the correct way to accept a drop of a volume onto my Dock tile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably your `Info.plist` is not properly set up.  It should include something like this:

```
CFBundleDocumentTypes =     (
    {
        LSItemContentTypes =             (
            "public.volume"
        );
    }
);
```

or you can use `CFBundleOSTypes` and `disk` instead if you need to support pre-10.5.

I was able to get `application:openFiles:` to work by doing this.

If you're already doing that, it's probably Launch Services getting confused... clean and rebuild your project, try a different user account, use `lsregister`, wave dead chickens, etc.

Comment: I had it with `com.apple.mount-point` and it ignored the drag. Removed that and left it only with the `OSType` 'disk' and that's how I got the tile to light up, but got the alert upon dropping. I'll try it with `public.volume` and let you know what happens.

Comment: Yup—you were completely correct. See my answer for the full update.

Answer (score 0):

> … the delegate is hooked up and is sent other delegate messages.

Or so I thought.

Mea culpa—I had, in fact, not even created the delegate. I'm not sure why I thought I had.

With the delegate instantiated and hooked up in the MainMenu nib, plus the Info.plist change Nicholas Riley suggested, the drops now work.